# Need keypath syntax for use in assign(to:_) in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm new to SwiftUI and have been following along with @[peter-friese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281221/peter-friese)'s [example SwiftUI/Firebase app](https://youtu.be/4RUeW5rUcww).

My example app works perfectly, but am now trying to modify slightly but am **unable to get the correct keypath syntax of in the `assign/map` in order to set a property.**

Relevantly (and slightly simplified), there is a struct for the data model:

```
struct Task: Codable, Identifiable {
  var title: String
  var status: Bool
  var flag: Bool
}
```

and a class for a view model:

```
class TaskCellViewModel {
  @Published var task: Task
  var iconName:String = "" 
}
```

In this tutorial a `map/assign` is used within the `TaskCellViewModel` to set the value of the `iconName` property in the instance of the `TaskCellViewModel` as follows:

```
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init(task: Task) {
    self.task = task
$task
   .map { task in
            task.status ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle"
        }
   .assign(to: \.iconName, on: self)
   .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

This works for setting the `iconName`. **What is the correct syntax to set the `flag` property on the `Task` itself?**

I have tried various combinations but none work, including:

```
.assign(to .\Task.task.flag, on: self)
.assign(to .\task.flag, on: self)
.assign(to .\Task.task.flag, on: TaskCellViewModel)
```

Using `Task.task.flag` it fails at runtime with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error or a type conversion compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type `AnswerRowViewModel.Type` to expected argument type `AnswerRowViewModel`.

PS given I'm learning and trying to follow along with the tutorials, I'm hoping for a answer to the assign/map question - as opposed to a workaround/alternative.

Comment: It's setting the value of the property in the Task. it is happening after the Task is created when updates happen. In the tutorial it works on properties of the TaskCellViewModel - I'm trying to use the same method but on a property of Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sink` instead

```
.sink { [weak self] flag in
   self?.task.flag = flag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the `assign` arguments you were looking for:

```swift
.assign(to: \Task.flag, on: self.task)
```

**BUT** this won't work here since `Task` is a struct. The first argument is a `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/maperror/assign(to:on:))) which doesn't work with a struct's value semantics. Your `TaskCellViewModel` is a `class`, so that's why it worked with `self`.

[As Asperi already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65536404/99714), you can use `sink` for this case and manually assign the value in the closure.